# Configure a Replica Set

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to configure a Replica Set with 2 members in local e 1 member on a cloud-server.
I started the two instance from local in this way:

```
mongod --port 27117 --dbpath mongodb/rs0-0 --logpath mongodb/rs0-0/mongo.log --replSet rs0 --fork 
mongod --port 27118 --dbpath mongodb/rs0-1 --logpath mongodb/rs0-1/mongo.log --replSet rs0 --fork
```

and then I started the instance on my cloud-server (after opened the port):

```
mongod --port 27119 --dbpath mongoRS/rs0-2 --logpath mongoRS/rs0-2/mongo.log --replSet rs0 --fork
```

So, I started the server to configure the Replica Set:

```
mongo --port 27117

rsconf = {
    _id: "rs0",
    members: [{
        _id: 0,
        host: "myLocalIP:27117"
    }]
}

rs.initiate( rsconf )
rs.add("myLocalIP:27118")
rs.add("myServerIP:27119")
```

So I tried to do Test Connections in both directions:

from my local's shell:

```
mongo --host myCloudServer --port 27119
```

I enter in the server but it's not the Replica Set instance

from cloud-server's shell, it fails:

```
mongo --host myLocalIP --port 27017
```

where is the error? Thanks

Comment: What was the output of rs.add() commands above? Did they returned {ok:1} ?

Comment: Have you confirmed that both your local instances and the cloud instance can connect with each other, using the ip addresses and ports given? It might be useful to use nmap for this, to confirm that there is no firewall blocking the connections for example.

Comment: The rs.add() returned ok.
To test connections: 

`mongo --host myLocalIp --port 27117
mongo --host myCloudIP --port 27119`

My local log say that the connection to myCloud-server was ok.
My cloud-server log say that the connection to myLocal port was refused. 
So the problem is on my local sistem. It's Ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 0):

I take it back about test connections.
Both connections from myLocal to remote-myCloud and vice-versa was refused